# They can take our lives, but they will never take our hats!

Tags: idiomatic-language

"They can take our lives, but they'll never take our hats"

What is the meaning of this? Is this an idiom?

Comment: Where did you fake this sentence from?

Comment: user:42184 called Andrew has it in his profile-it made me a smile...

Answer (score 4):

It's a mis-quote[reference/homage/paraphrase] of a famous movie line.
(presumably intentional for comedic effect... not that it's funny, without context ;)

> They can take our lives, but they will never take our freedom.

from the movie [Braveheart](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112573/)

[Short video clip of the specific scene at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zFAvzf0Mv0&ab_channel=Citarei ]

The movie is partly famous because of Mel Gibson's atrocious Scottish accent throughout the film.

TV Tropes - [Ooh Me Accents [sic] Slipping](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/OohMeAccentsSlipping/LiveActionFilms?from=OohMeAccentsSlipping.Film)

*Late edit:*
Your added comment on the OP gives it the needed context...
"[user:42184 called Andrew](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/42184/andrew) has it in his profile-it made me a smile... – Nana Goshadze"
Every year Stack Exchange has a light-hearted ["Winter Bash" contest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304340/winter-bash-2017-hats) in December... the prizes are hats for your SE avatar to wear.

Comment: This is the right answer.  At the end of the Winter Bash they turn off the hats thingie, but I refused to let go of mine and photoshopped it onto my icon.

Comment: I never thought to 'take' the hat to wear for the entire year, though I do change my avatar picture for the Winter Bash duration to a different frame from the same video - one that can wear a hat more easily - https://i.stack.imgur.com/tL0m5.png